# Proposed tag synonym: make [perl-hash] a synonym of [perl-data-structures]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[perl-hash](/questions/tagged/perl-hash) has 6 questions. It's not really a good tag, since a vast majority of the Perl hash questions are instead under [perl-data-structures](/questions/tagged/perl-data-structures) (100+ questions).

Therefore, I proposed to make [perl-hash](/questions/tagged/perl-hash) to be a synonym of [perl-data-structures](/questions/tagged/perl-data-structures).

If you agree, please vote: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl-data-structures/synonyms